# iOS Auto Layout >> View is not Changing its Size

Tags: ios, constraints, autolayout

I have a design for a screen that should look like this (other things will be added later, but I cannot seem to resolve the basis...):

[image]

I have added Constraints to determine the following:

- Both Labels are Constraint in spacing to the screen edges.
- Middle View is Horizontally and Vertically Constraint to the Middle of the Background View Center.
- I have added 4 Constraints to express Minimum and Maximum Vertical Spacing between the Middle View and the Labels (Current spacing as Maximum and Standard spacing as Minimum).
- I have also added 2 Constraints to the Middle View to define Spacings from the Screen right and left edges.

I thought that it should be enough, but in reality, when switching between Retina 3.5 and 4 the Bottom Label disappears and the Middle View is cut in the middle:

[image]

I have tried lowering the Middle View Content Hugging and Content Compression Priorities, and still no good.

Here are the Warnings I get:

[image]

Any idea how to resolve this?

Or alternatively, how to approach it differently (preferably, still using Auto Layout)?

Comment: I was able to resolve the ambiguous layout by setting a constant spacing between the Middle View and the Labels - as the Middle View size was reduced - but this is not what I'm trying to achieve. I don't mind that the spacing will reduce from it's current value - therefore I assumed that the Relational Spacing (grater than and less than) should supply enough data. But it seems like the Middle View is 'ignoring' these Constraints. Also, it ignores the Middle View Center Constraints (H & V).

Answer (score 0):

Add Equal Width & Equal Height constraints as well & It will work

[image]

Comment: To which objects have you added these constraints?

Comment: select all your views,labels & add this constraints. Mine is working fine.

Comment: Mine's are not... When I select all of them (3 objects) and mark the 2 Constraints definitions (as you suggest), the Add X Constraints button marks that there are 4 Constraints to be added, while in your example it states that 6 Constraints are to be added. Can you tell why we have a difference?

Comment: Then try to add a Bottom Spacing to nearest neighbor constraints to the yellow view. To add that click in the bottom red dotted lines in Spacing to nearest neighbor.

Comment: I already have a Spacing Constraint from the Yellow View - actually to both Labels - where I specify the Minimum Spacing to 'Standard' (i.e. 8 pixels).

Comment: Also, what is the meaning of "Equal Heights" what setting this Relational Constraint to compare between the Labels and the View, which clearly have different sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Add `TopSpaceToContainer` constraint for Top Label. Then add `width` and `height` constraints for your yellow view at the middle. Remove the multiple `vertical spacing` constraints given to the Top Label and Bottom Label.

Comment: I already have a Top Space to Container for the Top Label. How would adding Height Constraint to the Middle View supposes to fix the problem? As the whole idea is to have this View Height 'flexible' so it shrinks when presented in a 3.5 or in Landscape. Also, I've tried that and it didn't work...